# "Home Edition" license for Mathematica: country and upgrades

Tags: licensing, home-edition

I'm interested in buying a "Home Edition" license for Mathematica, but there's the following information which I'd like to know beforehand and which I cannot find online:

- As I'm about to buy it, the Wolfram website says "Software may not be registered for use outside the country of purchase". "may not be" - how can I find it out if it actually is or not? I'm usually based in Brazil but I'm currently travelling all around Europe, so if I buy it now in Europe will I be able to use it in the various European countries I'm travelling to as well as back in Brazil?
- The "Home Edition" license is valid for one year. If there're any Mathematica version upgrades during this year, would I get the upgrade for free or would I have to pay?

Many thanks!

Comment: While good questions, these are best answered by an official WRI representative.  Contacting their sales department or a message on the Wolfram Community will get you a more official response.

Comment: Bob is correct consult Wolfram directly.  For point 2 you get upgrades for the lifetime of your license, e.g. 1 year unless you renew.  So for example you can expect a few point releases of MMA10.0.x in 2015 at least.